# Widget Windows in UltimateListCtrl Won't Resize/Refresh

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxwidgets

My goal is to get a `ULC` that has a column of `TextCtrl`s that will dynamically resize the row as the user types, so if there is a much better way, say so.

Here is what I've tried:

The `ExpandoTextCtrl` is exactly what I want.  I have a working example, so I know I'm able to implement it correctly, I'm after a column of these:

```
import wx
import sys
import wx.lib.expando as ex

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        text = "\"I\'ll Be Missing You\" is a song recorded by American rapper Puff Daddy and American singer Faith Evans, featuring R&B group 112, in memory of fellow Bad Boy Records artist Christopher \"The Notorious B.I.G.\" Wallace, who was gunned down on March 9, 1997. --Wikipedia"
        self.edit_text = ex.ExpandoTextCtrl(self, value = text, size = (200,50))
        self.edit_text.SetMaxHeight(sys.maxint)

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="expando Demo")
        panel = TestPanel(self)
        self.Show()
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = TestFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

As you add or remove lines it adjusts the height on the fly, for any character (not just the number of newlines or something simple like that).

If I add it to a cell in an `UltimateListCtrl`, it has a static size which is approximately column width and 2 lines of text visible, so it won't even instantiate showing the entire text, but it also won't resize either.

I have the same problem with other types of `Window`s is the `list`.  I wrote a `button` that changes its size when you click it.  This code of mine (I can post if you want but it feels redundant) runs perfectly in a panel of its own or in a `Sizer` with other widgets, etc, but in the `ULC` it will only instantiate at the original size and never changes with calls to `button.SetSize()`.

I have researched bug reports for the `ULC` but haven't seen anything relevant and not fixed.  I have tried calling the `ULC`'s `Refresh()`, `Update()`, and `Show(False/True)` methods, and all of the above on the parent `Panel` and the `Frame` with no success.

Here is the code, based around a common example of the `ULC` online:

```
import wx
import sys
from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC
import wx.lib.expando as ex

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.sizes = self.size_gen()
        font = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)
        boldfont = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)
        boldfont.SetWeight(wx.BOLD)
        boldfont.SetPointSize(12)

        self.ultimateList = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self, agwStyle = wx.LC_REPORT
                                         | wx.LC_VRULES
                                         | wx.LC_HRULES
                                         | ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT)

        info = ULC.UltimateListItem()
        info._mask = wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT | wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE | wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT | ULC.ULC_MASK_CHECK
        info._image = []
        info._format = 0
        info._kind = 1
        info._text = "Artist Name"
        self.ultimateList.InsertColumnInfo(0, info)

        info = ULC.UltimateListItem()
        info._format = wx.LIST_FORMAT_RIGHT
        info._mask = wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT | wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE | wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT | ULC.ULC_MASK_FONT
        info._image = []
        info._text = "Title"
        info._font = boldfont
        self.ultimateList.InsertColumnInfo(1, info)

        info = ULC.UltimateListItem()
        info._mask = wx.LIST_MASK_TEXT | wx.LIST_MASK_IMAGE | wx.LIST_MASK_FORMAT
        info._format = 0
        info._text = "Genre"
        info._font = font
        info._image = []
        self.ultimateList.InsertColumnInfo(2, info)

        self.ultimateList.InsertStringItem(0, "Newsboys")
        self.ultimateList.SetStringItem(0, 1, "Go")
        self.ultimateList.SetStringItem(0, 2, "Rock")

        text = "\"I\'ll Be Missing You\" is a song recorded by American rapper Puff Daddy and American singer Faith Evans, featuring R&B group 112, in memory of fellow Bad Boy Records artist Christopher \"The Notorious B.I.G.\" Wallace, who was gunned down on March 9, 1997. --Wikipedia"
        self.ultimateList.InsertStringItem(1, "Puffy")
        edit_text = ex.ExpandoTextCtrl(self.ultimateList, value = text, size=(200,50))
        edit_text.SetMaxHeight(sys.maxint)
        self.ultimateList.SetItemWindow(1, col=1, wnd=edit_text, expand=True)
        self.ultimateList.SetStringItem(1, 2, "Pop")

        self.ultimateList.InsertStringItem(2, "Family Force 5")
        self.button = wx.Button(self.ultimateList, label='button', size =(200,200))
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)
        self.ultimateList.SetItemWindow(2, 1, self.button, expand=True)
        #self.ultimateList.SetStringItem(2, 1, "III")
        self.ultimateList.SetStringItem(2, 2, "Crunk")

        self.ultimateList.SetColumnWidth(0, 150)
        self.ultimateList.SetColumnWidth(1, 200)
        self.ultimateList.SetColumnWidth(2, 100)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.ultimateList, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def on_button(self, event):
        self.button.SetSize(self.sizes.next())

    def size_gen(self):
        sizes = [(150,200),(200,200),(80,80)]
        index = 0
        while True:
            yield sizes[index]
            index = index + 1
            if index > 2:
                index = 0

########################################################################
class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="MvP UltimateListCtrl Demo")
        panel = TestPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = TestFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**EDIT**

I've tried several more approaches now.  I got rid of all the column formatting and replaced those 3 blocks with simple`list.InsertColumn(index, label)` calls.  The most useful thing I did was remove the `expand=True` from the `ULC.SetItemWindow()` call.  This seems to have returned control of the button's width (but not height) to the button.  Since it starts at 150Wx200H, when I call `next` and it changes to 200x200, the button overflows into the next cell to the right.  When I call `next` again, commanding an 80x80 size, the button shrinks to 150x200, its unable to be set smaller than its initial size.

If I initialize the button smaller than I ever need, say 50x30, then I can set all the sizes (80,80;200,200) correctly in both dimensions, but the button then overflows into its neighbours to the right and below.

[image]
[image]

You can see that the list is not refreshing any of the rows.
You can also see that the widget maintains its original upper left corner position (maybe this is correct, but I don't think so)

If I add `list.Refresh/DoLayout/Layout/Update` to the `on_button`, it has no effect.

Dragging or repositioning the window (top level `Frame`) has no effect.
`ULC.SendSizeEvent` has no effect.

**Next Idea**
I also tried deleting the entire row and inserting a new button of new size, like so:

```
def on_button(self,event):

    new_size = self.sizes.next()
    print new_size
    l = self.ultimateList
    label = l.GetItemWindow(1, 1).GetLabel()
    l.DeleteItem(1)
    self.button = wx.Button(self.ultimateList, label=label, size=new_size)
    self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)
    l.InsertStringItem(1, 'Family Farce 5')
    l.SetItemWindow(1,1,self.button)
    l.SetStringItem(1,2,'Crunk')
```

I don't think this is an ok strategy, as destroying and rebuilding an `edit_text` on every keystroke sounds like it would have a whole lot of problems, but to be fair I haven't tried it yet.

Anyway, with the button I can call it and resizes correctly.  The problem is that the `ULC` doesn't redraw subsequent rows based on the new height, or even the initial height, but the default height of a row.  It does draw the recreated row with the button the correct height.

[image]

This time (deleting the line and adding a new line) I noticed resizing the window (top level `Frame`) forced the redraw, so I added `SendSizeEvent` to `on_button` and now the button works perfectly.

[image]

Apparently I've worked out how to replace a row with one of a new size.

So the question is still about `Window`s in a `ULC`, I can dynamically resize a widget, but **how can I force the ULC to redraw itself after sizing a widget?**

Another way to say it: **Why does `SendSizeEvent` force a refresh after inserting a new item into the list, but not after modifying an existing item?**  I could subclass the `ULC` and extend a particular method or property if I knew which one to do.  I've tried looking at the source but I can't make heads or tails of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: ULC creates the line heights only once and if the height is already there when painting a line, it wont do it again.

Furthermore: When you add a new window, the size gets written into the line object. This will never be done again and cannot be triggered by any means manually.

However:

If you adjust UltimateListCtrl like this it will work.

Function GetWindowSize of class UltimateListItemData (line 2863):

```
def GetWindowSize(self):
    """ Returns the associated window size. """
    wnd = self._wnd
    if wnd.GetSizer():      # the window is a complex one hold by a sizer
        size = wnd.GetBestSize()
    else:                   # simple window, without sizers
        size = wnd.GetSize()
    print(size)
    return size
```

In your code you need to invalidate the old line heights, so it gets recalculated:

```
def on_button(self, event):
    self.button.SetSize(self.sizes.next())
    self.ultimateList._mainWin.ResetLineDimensions(True)
    self.ultimateList._mainWin.RecalculatePositions()
```

Please note, that this modifies ULC and accesses private variables.

Lokla

Comment: Wonderful, thanks so much. I could tell I messed something like that but I'm relatively inexperienced with python and wx, and I kept getting lost in the 11000 line source. When I get home I'll try it and accept.

Comment: Its not working for me.  I tried subclassing `ULC` with your `GetWindowSize` method and replaced your `on_button` as shown.  I thought it might be some weird issue with the subclass so I modified the original `ultimatelistctrl.py`, same issue.  It acts just like the second screenshot in my first edit, the button resizes but the list doesn't redraw.  I'm not seeing the printed size (or any other output) in the term if that helps.

Comment: Did you notice that there are 2 GetWindowSize functions in the ULC file? First is located at 2020 and second one is located at 2857 in my version. You need to edit the one at 2857. Which is inside the UltimateListItemData class

Comment: I didn't notice that, the first time I just searched for `GetWindowSize` in the .py file, but now I have modified the correct one and it works just fine.  I'll try to think of a good way to subclass it myself or something so its less hacky, but in the meantime its working great with the `Button` and the `Expando` (catch the `ex.EVT_ETC_LAYOUT_NEEDED` event).

Cheers!